# JAVA.. IF statement inside for loop in java

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, if-statement, arraylist

Basically whenever the user clicks on option 2 in the main menu they get to deposit funds into an account of their choice. (This is my code for option 2).. For this example lets say we have 3 accounts. '1001', '1002' and '1003' this is their ID's. So i have this for loop which loops through the array of accounts which is called 'businesses' and has an if statement to see if the account exists or not.

```
System.out.println("Enter account you wish to deposit into: ");
depositRef = input.nextInt();

for(int i = 0; i < businesses.members.size(); i++) {
    //System.out.println(businesses.getCurrent(i).getAccRefNo()); a check to make sure all accounts exist. which they do.
    if (depositRef == businesses.getReferenceNo(i)) {
        System.out.println("Enter the amount you wish to deposit into " + businesses.getCurrent(i).getName() + "'s account: ");
        balance = input.nextDouble();
        businesses.getCurrent(i).deposit(balance);
    } else if (depositRef != businesses.getReferenceNo(i)) {
        System.out.print("Sorry Account doesnt exist. Try again!");
        return;
    }
}

break;
```

My problem being is that if we Entered '1003' the for loop will not keep looping until it reaches '1003' it will just say sorry account doesnt exist! how do i ammend this code so that it loops through until it matches? it only loops once and if it doesnt match '1001' then it throws an error.

If you think this question is missing anything that might help just say and ill happily add it in.

Comment: Use a map with the IDs as key in this case. This algorithm is highly inefficient. So you could simply map.get(id);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a return statement in the wrong conditional. You want to return (stop looking) if you found the account. Not if you didn't find it.

```
for(int i = 0; i < businesses.members.size(); i++) {
    if (depositRef == businesses.getReferenceNo(i)) {
        System.out.println("Enter the amount you wish to deposit into " + businesses.getCurrent(i).getName() + "'s account: ");
        balance = input.nextDouble();
        businesses.getCurrent(i).deposit(balance);
        return;
    }
}
System.out.print("Sorry Account doesnt exist. Try again!");
```

However, this sort of lookup is very inefficient, it will take O(n) time which means that it will be linearly slower for each account you add.

If you instead hold your accounts in a Map, you can access them in O(1) time, i.e. no matter how many accounts you have, they can always be accessed within the same time.

Comment: Thanks alot this done the trick.. I understand what you are saying about efficiency but this is for a uni assignment which i am fast running out of time to get done lol. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove the `return`

```
else { // redundant 'if (depositRef != businesses.getReferenceNo(i))'
    System.out.print("Sorry Account doesnt exist. Try again!");
    // return;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a `return` that shouldn't be there. Try with

```
else if (depositRef != businesses.getReferenceNo(i))
{
    System.out.print("Sorry Account doesnt exist. Try again!");
}
```

And to avoid useless loop after having found the right one, add the return here :

```
  if (depositRef == businesses.getReferenceNo(i)) {
        System.out.println("Enter the amount you wish to deposit into " + businesses.getCurrent(i).getName() + "'s account: ");
        balance = input.nextDouble();
        businesses.getCurrent(i).deposit(balance);
        return;
    }
```

But yeah, the way you do it is highly inefficient. You should check out `Map` to do it in a better way.